# Doubts in code of multi-threading using ArrayBlockingQueue and mutex

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, blockingqueue

I am trying to write a multithreaded code. But seriously I can't understand from where can I start. My head is banging also. Please help me.

**My task is,**

1. There is one queue of length 1, known as `pending_tasks`, that contains tasks which requires some processing.
2. There is another queue of length 1, known as `completed_tasks`, that contains tasks which completes processing., and ready to deliver.

**My implementation thinking,**

1. Firstly make two blocking queues, `pending_tasks` and `completed_tasks`.
2. One thread(producer) always listening for tasks that comes from outside, if gets put into `pending_tasks`.
3. One thread(consumer) always ready to take tasks from `pending_tasks` and starts processing , and after that put into into `completed_tasks`.
4. Then again comes to `pending_tasks`, and whenever any tasks come, start the same processing.
5. Basically, its a single producer-single consumer problem.

**My confusion,**

I know that it can be code by using ArrayBlockingQueue and Mutex. But I didn't understand how can I start this. I have good understanding of mutex, I read about mutex from this [link](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=98786), and have good understanding of blockingQueue also, as I read lots of questions on this site.

Can you please give me some implementation guidance, so that I can write this multi-threaded code.

I already wrote some code for the same, but that is not achieve the final goal of my task.

Thanks in advance. Looking for your kind reply.

**EDIT NO. 1**

Please see my below code. This code works fine, but this code has one functionality missing. Please help me to add that, give some guidance to do that.

**Functionality is,**

1. When producer thread puts some value in pending_task queue, then it waits for some time there. If in that time consumer gives the result to consumer, then its OK. Otherwise, it says time out, and producer takes another value and pput that in pending_task queue, and the same process starts.

**Please help me in adding above functionality. I think we have to communicate between producer thread and consumer thread, and thread communication is done by using Mutex(I think). Please help me implementing the same**

**My code,**

**MultiThread Class**

```
package multithread;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class MultiThread {

    public static BlockingQueue<Integer> pending_task;
    public static BlockingQueue<Integer> completed_task;

    public MultiThread(int length) {
        pending_task = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(length, true);
        completed_task = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(length, true);
    }
}
```

**Producer Class**

```
package multithread;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("PRODUCER: Try to put value  " + i + "  in the pending queue");
                MultiThread.pending_task.put(i);
                System.out.println("PRODUCER: Successfully put value  " + i + "  in the pending queue, now its turn to consumer");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer Class**

```
package multithread;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("CONSUMER: Try to take value from the pending queue");
                int val = MultiThread.pending_task.take();
                System.out.println("CONSUMER:  Successfully take value, and that is   " + val);
                System.out.println("CONSUMER: Processing starts");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("CONSUMER: Processing ends");
                System.out.println("CONSUMER: Try to put that  that value in  completed queue, and the value is   " + val);
                MultiThread.completed_task.put(val);
                System.out.println("CONSUMER: Successfully put into completed queue");

                //Serve this value to the corresponding user
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**DeliveryBoy Class**

```
package multithread;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DeliveryBoy implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("DELIVERYBOY: Waiting for the value near completed queue");
                int val = MultiThread.completed_task.take();
                System.out.println("DELIVERYBOY:  Succesfully take value from completed queue and the vlue is  " + val);
                //Serve this value to the corresponding user
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
package multithread;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        MultiThread ml = new MultiThread(1);
        new Thread(new Producer()).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
        new Thread(new DeliveryBoy()).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very likely to be closed unless you post your current code and formulate a question around why that doesn't work. Currently, your question is very vague and open-ended and can only be answered by someone writing the whole thing for you.

Comment: Your mutex link is fairly old. While you can still use wait/notify for consumer/producer patterns, there are more useful and higher-level solutions. I suggest you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/.

Comment: @DuncanJones I added my code in question. Please see that

Comment: @DuncanJones Please see my code, and give some guidance, please.

Comment: Please see EDIT NO. 1, it shows my code, and some functionality , that I want to add. Please suggest some expert advise. How can I do that. If possible please give some implementation guide.

Answer (score 1):

From [ArrayBlockingQueue#put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#offer%28E%29)

> public void put(E e)
>            throws InterruptedException
>
> Inserts the specified element at the tail of this queue, **waiting for
>   **space to become available if the queue is full**

From [ArrayBlockingQueue#take](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29)

> public E take()
>          throws InterruptedException
>
> Description copied from interface: BlockingQueue Retrieves and removes
>   the head of this queue, **waiting if necessary until an element becomes
>   available**.

So all you need to do is call these methods from your threads.
Try this (study the javadoc) and when you have a more specific problem you can ask again.

Comment: The thing that you explain in answer is already known to me. I feel that I am already good in theory perspective. But I am unable to convert that into code. I made some code(see the updated part of question), but that have lots of issues , please help me to solve these. and yes I want to add mutex concept also in that.

Comment: This is the question, how can I implement this, there is something missing in thia, please just guide me, how can I implement threading here , and mutex also in this.

Comment: @devsda:Check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: According to this page, I have to make different classes for prodcer, consumer ? But actually I want this all performs in the  same module of one class. Can I do that ?

Comment: Please see EDIT NO. 1, it shows my code, and some functionality , that I want to add. Please suggest some expert advise. How can I do that. If possible please give some implementation guide.

Comment: You need a `Runnable` for `Producer` and a `Runnable` for `Consumer`.These will share the same instance of `BlockingQueue`. You start them both and one will place to the queue the other will remove concurrently as they are *run* by different threads you *started*

Comment: I have already done the same thing, that you said, and posted in the `Edit no 1`. Please see that code. I want to add one functionality , I also mentioned that also in Edit no. 1.

Comment: Please See my Edit no.1, please help me.